# Magento 2 Create Catalog Price Rule Programmatically

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I have used the below code to create catalog price rule programmatically. It creates the rule,but the conditions are not saved.

```
$catalogPriceRule = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule');
$catalogPriceRule
    ->setName('name')
    ->setDescription('description')
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setCustomerGroupIds(array(1))
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
    ->setFromDate('')
    ->setToDate('')
    ->setSimpleAction('by_fixed')
    ->setDiscountAmount(10)
    ->setStopRulesProcessing(0);

$conditions = array();
$conditions[1] = array(
    'type' => 'catalogrule/rule_condition_combine',
    'aggregator' => 'any',
    'value' => "1",
    'new_child' => ''
);

$i = 1;
$conditions['1--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'catalogrule/rule_condition_product_found',
    'value' => 1,
    'aggregator' => 'all',
    'new_child' => '',
);

$conditions['1--1--1'] = array(
    'type' => 'catalogrule/rule_condition_product',
    'attribute' => 'sku',
    'operator' => '==',
    'value' => '24-UB02',
);
$catalogPriceRule->setData('conditions',$conditions);
$catalogPriceRule->loadPost($catalogPriceRule->getData());
$catalogPriceRule->save();
$catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
```

Comment: Can u explain what condition are you try to build?

Comment: Want to add some skus in the condition.

Comment: How can i create cart rule with condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check below Code.

> Reference: \Magento\CatalogRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Catalog\Save

Before saving rule **validate** data It's helping for saving Correct value

```
$model = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule');
$model->setName('name') 
    ->setDescription('description') 
    ->setIsActive(1) 
    ->setCustomerGroupIds(array(1))
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
    ->setFromDate('') 
    ->setToDate('') 
    ->setSimpleAction('by_fixed') 
    ->setDiscountAmount(10) 
    ->setStopRulesProcessing(0);  

$conditions = array();
$conditions["1"] = array
        (
            "type" => "Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine",
            "aggregator" => "all",
            "value" => 1,
            "new_child" => ""
        );
$conditions["1--1"] = array
        (
            "type" => "Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product",
            "attribute" => "sku",
            "operator" => "==",
            "value" => "24-UB02"
        );

$model->setData('conditions',$conditions);

// Validating rule data before Saving
$validateResult = $model->validateData(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($model->getData()));
if ($validateResult !== true) {
    foreach ($validateResult as $errorMessage) {
        echo $errorMessage;
    }                                       
    return;
}

try {                   
    $model->loadPost($model->getData());
    $model->save(); 

    $ruleJob = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Job');
    $ruleJob->applyAll();
    echo "rule created";
} catch (Exception $e) {                    
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```