# Magento 2.2.5 : Save Catalog Rule Conditions

Tags: database, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

I am trying to save catalog rule condtions from my custom module, below is the array I get in my controller save.php

```
[rule] => Array
    (
        [conditions] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
                        [aggregator] => all
                        [value] => 1
                        [new_child] => 
                    )

                [1--1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product
                        [attribute] => attribute_set_id
                        [operator] => ==
                        [value] => 4
                    )

            )

    )
```

The array is further modified to conditions by doing:

```
if (isset($data['rule'])) {
                $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
                unset($data['rule']);
            }
```

My database table column for conditions is **conditions_serialized** as it is in catalogrule table. Now my question is what are the steps I am missing in between -- because when I save a record I get the error:

> Something went wrong while saving the record !

Any one who has implemented this might be having a better insight in to the problem , please advise .

Comment: Try by printing array from saving catalog rule by admin, and see is the array thus formed is same as your array. The issue can be due to missing array entries needed in the db.

Comment: @LAW Yes it is same.

Comment: If you try printing array in the core controller with save action can you check if it reaches there?

Comment: I am saving this with my own controller and own ui form , the values are coming form my own custom form.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156119/magento-2-create-catalog-price-rule-programmatically

Compared your array with this, seemed slightly different can you remove the difference and hence try?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the *loadPost* function of the model.

$model->loadPost($data)->save();

An example is:

```
 /**
 * Save action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute() {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {

        /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Example $model */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Entrepids\Warranty\Model\Warranty');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('example_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

        if (isset($data['rule'])) {
            $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
            unset($data['rule']);
        }

        try {
            $model->loadPost($data)->save();                       
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved this warranty.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['warranty_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the warranty.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['warranty_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('warranty_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the Below link is a full Example.

[**Click Here For Part 1**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344611/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344612/82670)

[**Click Here For Part 3**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344613/82670)

**[Check condition with products in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344617/82670)**

***I Hope This Helps You.***